# jquery ui tabs not resizing properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to use JQuery UI tabs but the content doesn't seem to be resizing properly.  Only the displayed tab resizes properly.  This seems like it should be such a simple thing.  I've tried setting:

```
`width:auto` and
`width:100%`
```

Auto keeps the width from spilling out over the tabbed area but 100% seems to fill the tabbed area and resizes (but spills out).  Please help.

Here's a link to the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/CatNLane/adhmxdu6/

Comment: So I have found an answer but it seems like something that shouldn't have to do.  See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CatNLane/cuvj8f24/1/  Basically I'm finding the old height and forcing the new height to be the same in the beforeActivate section of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the two 100% width tabs overflowing is due to the .map divs having a width of 100%, but the surrounding divs have padding (inherited from the jquery-ui CSS file as they get a ui-tabs-panel class added). You can better see what is happening if you give the .map class a different colored background.